# How to eject physical external NVME Thunderbolt enclosure on M1 Mac so it doesn't show in diskutil list / Disk Utilities?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk

I have an external NVME enclosure with 40Gbps Thunderbolt 4 connection (Acasis TBU405 M1 Pro) with a Samsung 980 Pro 2TB installed, connected to the M1 Mac Mini (2020) Thunderbolt port, running Sonoma 14.0.

I want to eject/unmount the physical drive so I can disconnect the drive without getting +1 in the "Unsafe Shutdowns" field of `smartctl -a` report.

The current drive partition setup is 2 volumes in 1 container. I seem to be only able to eject the 2 volumes, but not the "External Physical Disk" (top-most item) of this external SSD drive.

As you can see in the screenshot in Disk Utilities, the two volumes are greyed out and the drive doesn't show on the desktop. But the physical drive "Samsung SSD 980 Pro 2TB" is still showing in the list.

I tried these commands (with and without sudo) in the terminal but it doesn't unmount the drive fully (the light on the enclosure is still on after the commands, and the drive still remains in the list in Disk Utilities).

```
diskutil eject disk4
diskutil umount disk4
diskutil unmountDisk force disk4
```

The output of these commands is all "successful unmount" or "ejected successfully".

How can I actually unmount it? I don't want to have a high unsafe shutdowns number on the smart report, possibly damaging the SSD.

PS. When I click the unmount button in the GUI Disk Utilities window of the top-most level of an external drive, e.g. a spinning HDD, a flash drive, or an SD card, they all disappear off the list on the left sidebar.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility showing the configuration of the 2 TB Samsung external drive]

Output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB    disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB  disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         2.0 TB    disk4s2

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE      IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB    disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume 980PRO2TB               58.4 GB   disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume MMM1 Timemachine        75.8 GB   disk5s3
```

Comment: That's just the device, not a volume. No volumes are mounted.

Comment: I agree with @benwiggy, you have unmounted all the volumes on the drive. You should edit your question and ask how to eject the drive so the drive does not appear in the Disk Utility or in the output from `diskutil list`. BTW, I unplug my Samsung X5 Thunderbolt 3 drive only after first shutting down the Mac.

Comment: So it's the "device", not volume - got it. But if the volumes are all unmounted, why am I still getting +1 unsafe shutdown everytime I disconnect the drive? That's the reason I think, it needs to be "fully removed" from the list to prevent that from happening. Maybe I'll just unplug the drive only when the Mac is off completely then. Thanks @benwiggy and david-anderson.

Comment: What is listed in `/Volumes`?

Comment: @benwiggy, 980PRO2TB, MMM1 Timemachine and Macintosh HD

Comment: Well, if they are listed in /Volumes, then they are not unmounted.